# How to match data points in D3.js to match x-axis?

Tags: d3.js

I try to adapt the following script.
But unfortunately I can not match the data points to the legend on the x-axis?
How can I move the data points / the line to the right to match the legend on the x-axis?
Source is: http://mund-consulting.com/Blog/visualizing-web-page-views-using-d3js/

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>
        var margin = { top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
            width = 900,
            height = 400;

        var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

        var tip = d3.tip()
          .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
          .offset([-10, 0])
          .html(function (d) {
              return "<strong>"+d.MonthName+": </strong>
                      <span style='color:black'>" + d.PageViews + "</span>";
          })

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg.call(tip);

        d3.csv("mc_monthly_pageview_2014.csv", function (error, data) {
            x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.MonthName; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.PageViews; })]);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
              .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Page Views");

            var line = d3.svg.line()
                 .x(function (d) { return x(d.MonthName); })
                 .y(function (d) { return y(d.PageViews); });

            svg.selectAll("path.line")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .attr("class", "line")
                    .attr("d", line(data));

            svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "dot")
                .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.MonthName); })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.PageViews); })
                .attr("r", 4.5)
                .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

Exchange

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
```

with

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()          
            .rangePoints([0, width]);
```